# How to use length function to count rows and columns in R

Tags: r, count, rows

I have some data in R, I need to use length function to count how many rows and columns in this data, the requirement ask for one line code.

```
data(airquality)
?airquality
air = airquality
head(air)
```

Comment: `dim(airquality)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dim` to get the dimensions of the dataset

```
dim(airquality)
```

---

`length` for `dataframe` gets the count of number of columns.  For number of rows, if we need to use `length`, then subset one of the columns and get the `length`

```
nc <- length(airquality)
nr <- length(airquality[[1]])
```

Comment: Many thanks. I use nrow(air); ncol(air) but think this is two codes, which must not satisfy the requirement.

Comment: @Annaavaya  Are you saying that you cannot use `dim`

Comment: or for a single line you could do `c(length(airquality[[1]]), length(airquality))` but that's just a long way of doing `dim`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option by using `length`

```
nc <- length(airquality)
nr <- length(t(airquality))/length(airquality)
```